# How to get data from 3rd level table using joins [Laravel]

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, join

I want to get quantity of the product which is stored in **bd_product_item_ledgers** using the primary key (ID) of **bd_products**

**bd_products** is linked to **bd_product_ledgers**
Then, **bd_product_ledgers** is linked to **bd_product_item_ledgers**

table: bd_products

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id |  name  |    description   | image     | created_at | updated_at
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | shoe   | this is a shoe   | 15243.jpg | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

table: bd_product_ledgers

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id |  product_id  |  cost    | created_at | updated_at
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |      1       | 500.00   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

table: bd_product_item_ledgers

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id |  product_ledger_id |  quantity  | created_at | updated_at
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |          1         |   200      |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I can get the cost of the product because there is ID present there, but how can i get the quantity also?

Simple MySQL Query Or Laravel eloquent etc anything would be good.

Thanks!

Comment: join on `product_ledger_id.id` and `bd_product_item_ledgers.product_ledger_id`  - ps those are some long column and table names.  So  `FROM bd_products JOIN bd_product_ledgers ON bd_products.id = bd_product_ledgers.product_id  JOIN bd_product_item_ledgers ON product_ledger_id.id = bd_product_item_ledgers.product_ledger_id`

Comment: Basically using your tables if you imagine a diagonal line from the first column of the top table to the second column of the second table.  Then the first column of the second table to the second column of the third table.  Sort of like a zig zag pattern... lol

Comment: Well yeah you're right, these are long column names. I was making a silly mistake, i wasn't writing the correct column names that's what made made me pull my hairs and i put the question here. anyways! thanks for your suggestion anyhow. :) @ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: My general rule is each table gets one word to describe it, unless it's a Junction table (Many to Many) those get two plural words one from each table.  `bd_products`, `bd_ledgers` and `bd_lineitems`

Comment: Duly noted. Thanks for the knowledge :) @ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: Yea naming conventions become a big deal as your complexity grows.  I cant stand mixed casing mixed plurals etc... lol  To much hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create three models Product,Item,ledgers and define your relationship ledgers in product model and item in ledgers model than you can get data using with query like,

```
$data = Product::with('ledgers.item')->get();
```

Comment: So it will get cost from ledgers table and quantity from item table as you suggest? @pal

Comment: yes using with method and relationship you will get the data you need but you have to be careful for your naming convention. @Mohsin

Comment: Ok. ill try this way too it looks more concise and clearer. @pal

Answer (score 1):

I am not Sure but i have created demo project with thr following tables and enterd the data provided by you

> **ITS PURLY DB FACADE VERSION**

**[IF YOU NEED IN ELOQUENT WAY PLEASE SHARE
 YOUR MODEL NAMES]**

```
public function index()
    { 
        $selctArray = [
                'bd_products.name',
                'bd_products.description',
                'PRDLED.cost as productCost',
                'PRDITLED.quantity as productQuantity',

        ];

        $joinQuery = DB::table('bd_products')
                        ->leftJoin('bd_product_ledgers as PRDLED','PRDLED.product_id','=','bd_products.id')
                        ->leftJoin('bd_product_item_ledgers as PRDITLED','PRDITLED.product_ledger_id','=','PRDLED.id')
                        ->select($selctArray)->get();
dd($joinQuery);

        }
```

[image: QUERY IMAGE]
please comment below if it has not satisfied your requirement and improve your question

Comment: I did it the same way with lil tweak. made a scope in Product model to get all products and then applied join on bd_product_ledgers and bd_product_item_ledgers. and it worked like a charm. 
***********
public function scopeAllProducts($query) {
        return $query->join('product_ledgers', 'products.id', '=', 'product_ledgers.product_id')
            ->join('product_item_ledgers', 'product_ledgers.id', '=', 'product_item_ledgers.product_ledger_id')
            ->select('products.*','product_ledgers.cost AS op_cost','product_item_ledgers.quantity AS op_quantity');
    }
***********

Comment: yes that's cool and scopes are working fine and try to add `alais` names its quite clear such as  `bd_product_item_ledgers as PRDITLED`

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) yeah ill keep that in mind to use aliases @Manojkiran.A

Comment: i don't know why you marked the `relation answer as accepted.` You just asked for the `joins` and that's what i was done. **You Doesn't asked for the relations**

Comment: I said in the last lines that simple MySQL query or laravel eloquent etc anything would be good. So @pal suggested about relations and it worked fine too with less code. Although i did upvoted your answer because its also another way to achieve same thing. Accepted answer solved problem in one line.